# How to Create Rounded Corner Shape ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How to make simple ListView in Android, I am making a program in which i am getting ListView in this style:

[image]

**Adapter.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- Title Of Song-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    >

   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/black"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I want to make this kind of simple List **[same List SHAPE]** , please see below screen:

[image]

Comment: the image that you have posted you want the same design

Comment: Create custom List view!

Comment: @RobinHood i can create stylish custom ListView but not able to create this kind of simple ListView

Comment: @Sonali I POSTED MY ANSWER CHECK THAT.

Comment: post your email id i will mail the complete setup i have done for you

Comment: Use adapters , create single view  then use in listview. , use your own logic , .

Comment: i have posted my answer see that will help you to get u r goal

Comment: @Sonali have you tried my code.if any issue let me know

Comment: @all i just required ListView Design, you all can do delete your codes, i have written clearly i need to make this kind of List, i did not write i need code to make this kind of List, so why my question downvoted answer me those have downvoted, and thanks to all of you those have answered, but my issue still not solved, please see list posted by me and what i want i hope you will get the difference

Comment: see the list_row.xml that you have to inflate in your main xml that will have your ListView.pass the value by the adapter and set the value as you want .

Comment: if still not got the design i have created for you in list_row.xml le me know i will updated that .that is how i can help u

Comment: @Sonali updated the answer see that change the color code in it as per your requirement thanks..!!!!All the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your requirement

create a shape file in your drawable folder .Put this xml in it and change the color as per your requirement .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shape_my">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#636161" />
    <padding android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
    <corners android:radius="24dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the ListView set the background `android:background="@drawable/shape"`

**list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/expiry_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/category"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:text="Text here."
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me, please check new screen shot i posted using your XML script, but i need same List Shape, i hope you are getting my point'

Comment: @Sonali you need a line also in the left side ??that will be blue .and see you Category is like 1,2,3, you have to do this is your base adapter class dyanmically you have to add it up

Comment: why friend why you are not getting my point, see the shape of List, i just want to get that shape for my List

Comment: @Sonali you want corner shape on the listview

Comment: Yeah i am looking for Corner Shape ListView, for delay sorry facing Internet Connection problem

Comment: please check i replied

Answer (score 4):

You  need to create a custom adapter to populate custom type list view 
you can follow the following step by step
Step 1 
Create a Class that contains attribute you want to load data of them as following

```
public class Rec {
private String name;
private String city;


public Rec(String name, String city) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
```

}

Create a Custom adapter that have your record class and its attribute in that 
as following

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Rec> {
Context context;
public customAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<Rec> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view;
    Rec currentRec = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.reclist,parent,false);

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    name.setText(currentRec.getName());
    city.setText(currentRec.getCity());

    //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    return view;



}
```

Now create an Xml for your list View that you want to show as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1" />
```

Now create your Main class in which you populate your list view and push data accordingly  as following :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
List<Rec> recList ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recList = new ArrayList<Rec>();

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    recList.add(new Rec("Ali","Lahore"));
    recList.add(new Rec("Tahir","Karachi"));
    recList.add(new Rec("Qasim","Islamabad"));
    recList.add(new Rec("Bilal","BWP"));
    recList.add(new Rec("Akhtar","Pindi"));

    listView.setAdapter(new customAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,recList));

}
```

}

Create your layout of your main activity as following :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
</ListView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="112dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

here is your complete custom List View with dynamic data

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs re-factoring for your requirement.

These examples might help you out.

1- [Simple list with arrow to move forward](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/building-a-custom-fancy-listview-in-android/)

2- [Advance Custom List with arrow](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

```
Update your Layout! with corresponding image for arrow and variable names!
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <!-- Title Of Song-->

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Name"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"/>


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />


        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowImage"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a list adapter and set the layout as you want.
for an example:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListShipsActivity.this, ArrayList,
                        R.layout.layout_as_you_want, new String[] {
                                "item1","item2"}, //elements of the item in the list
                        new int[] { R.id.text_view1, R.id.text_view2 }); //ids of the layout elements
```

after that create the layout xml file as you want
In your case, like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>


</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

ps: add the arrow image to drawable folder in your project